# Runtime exception when using System.Web.Http.HttpRouteCollectionExtensions.MapHttpRoute

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

Getting a runtime exception when using MapHttpRoute extension method

Library: Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi (5.2.4), System.Web.Http (5.2.4)
Exception:

```
System.MissingMethodException
  HResult=0x80131513
  Message=Method not found: 'System.Web.Http.Routing.IHttpRoute System.Web.Http.HttpRouteCollectionExtensions.MapHttpRoute(System.Web.Http.HttpRouteCollection, System.String, System.String, System.Object, System.Object, System.Net.Http.HttpMessageHandler)'.
```

Web.config dependent assembly mapping is also present

```
<dependentAssembly>
     <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
     <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.4.0" newVersion="5.2.4.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

I have tried re-installing the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi library but to no avail.

Comment: Did you clean and rebuild the solution?

Comment: Yes, cleared nuget cache and packages also.